# TSportal Web Part Problems

Tags: web-part

Has anyone else had any experience using the TSPortalWebPart, we have put it onto our Sharepoint to give people access to applications but it seems very hit and miss as to if it works:

- Sometimes when you go onto the page, no application at all show up in the part. This is across various machines, sometime they show sometimes they dont
- Loading the page can sometimes be very slow
- Putting the part on any page apart from the root site page breaks the entire page after iis restarts or recycles its processes

We could have done something wrong along the way, but it does seem to be hit and miss as to if it works or not. We are on Sharepoint 2010, the terminal servers are windows 2008 RC2 servers

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we have managed to work out the issues with the no icons showing and slow page loading, it turned out to be an issue with one of the servers in the farm, see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5974.aspx for info on how we fixed it